# What is the meaning of the "lasso loop" on circuit diagram?

Tags: schematics, symbol, pinout

I've never seen this "loop" structure in a circuit diagram before.

- **Pin 6** has a line that loops around the lines from pins 5 and 9.
- **Pin 7** has a line that loops around all other lines, except the *?resistor?* between pins 1 and 6.

[image: Nellcor Pulse Oximeter Pinout]

> ***NOTE:** This pinout diagram is for the `db9` connector on a [Nellcor Pulse Oximeter](https://www.sensoronics.com/products/nellcor-oximax-compatible-disposable-spo2-sensor?variant=21456204359&_vsrefdom=adwords&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIn8jqs8CO3QIVENvACh1alQxcEAQYBSABEgIFyfD_BwE)*

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The loops represent a shield around cable that then connects to the connector pin indicated by the line from the loop.

In your example there is a two wire pair that is shielded and then that is contained with some other wires and an overall outer shield.

Comment: Follow up question, should the shielding be connected to ground?

Comment: The shields should be connected to the pins shown in the diagram.

Comment: No. The schematic is for a connector, cable and sensor assembly. Appropriate connections for the shields are determined by what is on the other  side of the D-9 connector pins 6 and 7.

Comment: Any idea what the purpose of the resistor is?

Comment: @Silicomancer - The resistor could be one of several different things. Here are my ideas: (a) ID Resistor to indentify particular sensor unit based upon resistor value. (b) Calibration resistor that matches the sensor to a standardized interface input. (c) Bias resistor to adjust the photo sensor to compensate for photo transistor variations.